# How to display unicoded dictionary values

Tags: python, unicode, dictionary, utf-8

As an example, in Linux Python 2.7.3 I have unicoded characer é (LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE) in a dictionary and I try to display it as é:

```
>>> mydict = {'mykey':u'é'}
>>> mydict.values()
[u'\xe9']
>>> mydict['mykey']
u'\xe9'
>>> str(mydict.values())
"[u'\\xe9']
>>> print mydict.values()
[u'\xe9']
```

As a matter of fact I have the same challenge when the value is utf-8 coded:

```
>>> cdict ={'key2':'é'}
>>> cdict
{'key2': '\xc3\xa9'}
>>> print cdict.values()
['\xc3\xa9']
>>> cdict['key2']
'\xc3\xa9'
```

After searching answer from documentation and several similar questions I haven't found an answer. I would appreciate if somebody could give me a clear explanation with an example how to do this properly.

Comment: you are never actually printing anything, you are asking the repl to give you a representation of something. try playing around with `print` and `repr()` to see what i mean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually attempt to print the value, and not the dict or list they are in.

For example:

```
>>> mydict = {'mykey':u'é'}
>>> for value in mydict.values(): 
...   print value
... 
é
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. I am afraid I had simplified my question too much. I will reformulate and post a new question to the real problem I have. It is actually not related to printing but using the unicode typed dictionary values when normal strings are expected when inserting column values with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter outputs the string representation of the object. As the other answer states, if you print the value you will have the character displayed correctly.

Otherwise you will have to build the string yourself:

```
>>> mydict = {'mykey':u'é', 'myotherkey': 'x'}
>>> print '\n'.join(u"{}: {}".format(*pair) for pair in mydict.items())
mykey: é
myotherkey: x
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, printing a `dict` will print its keys/values `repr` not their `str`. To print the way you want use this snippet:

```
print "{%s}" % ", ".join("%s: '%s'" % pair for pair in mydict.items())
```

Obs.: In Python 2 an unicode string `repr` is surrounded by quotes but their `str` is not, remove the single quotes if you don't want them.